# Best Method for Updating Dropdown Selection and Text Area on submit

Tags: php, mysql, database

I am coding a PHP page that has a dropdown status selection and a text area for comments. Currently, I am having trouble figuring out how to code so that the dropdown list and text area will update correctly on submit.

I have set the default of the dropdown to display '---Select Status---' with no values.

My problem is: whenever I choose a status and make changes in the comments area, only the status gets updated, the comment remains the same. I was wondering if there's a more efficient way to do this..

UPDATE: I have given it some thought... there are 4 scenarios:

1. status changed / comments changed
2. status unchanged / comments changed
3. status changed / comments unchanged
4. status unchanged / comments unchanged

How do I go about coding this so that it updates on all occasions?

Here's my code for dropdown status / comment text area:

```
// this is the function for status dropdown menu
function statusDropdown($case){
    print("<b>Status:</b>");
    $dropdown = "<select name = 'status'><option selected='selected' value=NULL>--Select Status--</option>";

    $connection = getMySqlConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT STATUS_ID, STATUS_NAME FROM primary_status_lookup ORDER BY STATUS_ID ASC"; 
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    while($record=mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            $dropdown .= "<option value = '{$record['STATUS_ID']}'> {$record['STATUS_NAME']}</option>";
    }
    $dropdown .="</select>";
    echo $dropdown;

}

//This part incorporates Status dropdown & Comments (text area)

function tableStatus($case) {
    $connection = getMySqlConnection();
    $sql = "SELECT statistics_status, statistics_comments FROM cases WHERE caseid='".$case."'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

    if($result!== FALSE){
            while ($record = mysql_fetch_row($result)) {
                $status=$record[0];
                $comments=$record[1];

            print("<form><p>");

            showStatusComment($case);
            statusDropdown($case);
        print("<input type=hidden name='case' value='".$case."'/>");
        print("&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<label><b>Comments:</b><textarea name='comments' cols=70 rows=2 >".$comments."</textarea></label><br/><br/>");
        print("<input type='submit' name='submit' value='Submit'/></form>");


        }
    }
```

}

Here's my code for updating the data:

```
function saveTableStatus($case)
{
    //retrieve selected status
    if(isset($_REQUEST['status'])) {
        $status = $_REQUEST['status'];
    }

    //retrieve typed comments
    if(isset($_REQUEST['comments'])) {
        $comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
    }

    if($status=='NULL') {
        print("<p class='error'>No status selected, please select a status and try again.</p>");
    }
    else if (($status!=='NULL')){
        $connection = getMySqlConnection();
        mysql_query("START TRANSACTION", $connection);
        $result= mysql_query("Update cases Set statistics_status=".$status.", statistics_comments =".mysql_real_escape_string($comments)." Where caseid='".mysql_real_escape_string($case)."'", $connection);
            if($result) {
                mysql_query("COMMIT", $connection);
                print("<p class='saved'>Table Status Updated!</p>");
            } else {
                mysql_query("ROLLBACK", $connection);
            }
            mysql_close($connection);

        }
}
```

Comment: The mysql_ functions have been deprecated, you should look into using either MySQLi or PDO

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$result= mysql_query("Update cases Set statistics_status=".$status.", statistics_comments =".mysql_real_escape_string($comments)." Where caseid='".mysql_real_escape_string($case)."'", $connection);
```

This statement should be

```
$result= mysql_query("Update cases Set statistics_status=".$status.", statistics_comments ='".mysql_real_escape_string($comments)."' Where caseid='".mysql_real_escape_string($case)."'", $connection);
```

Check the quotations added for "statistics_comments" column.

Answer (score 2):

Where's the `showStatusComment($case)` Function that you write ?.
If you forget to write function  `showStatusComment()` then please write some code in that function that handles comments.

Answer (score 1):

You have used `value=NULL` in HTML, and checked it against 'NULL' string. The major amendment you need in your code will be to remove the `value=NULL` attribute.

Next, you need to check it against NULL, not 'NULL':

```
if ( $status == NULL ) {
    print("<p class='error'> . . . </p>");
}
```

That should apparently solve the problem. Moreover, refer to Rameshkrishnan S's reply with modification:

```
$result= mysql_query("Update cases Set statistics_status='".$status."', statistics_comments ='".mysql_real_escape_string($comments)."' Where caseid='".mysql_real_escape_string($case)."'", $connection);
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer to Nj Subedi answer, You have to used value==null in your condition cause null should not be a string.

And for the re - modification of the code in your UPDATE query. You should use this.

```
$result =  mysql_query("Update cases Set statistics_status='".$status."',statistics_comments ='".mysql_real_escape_string($comments)."' Where caseid=".mysql_real_escape_string($case), $connection);
```

NOTE: I remove the quotes in the caseid because i assumed that it is not a string. So no need to put quotes.

And by the way you should not use mysql_query cause it is now deprecated. Use MySQLi or PDO_MySQL instead.

Answer (score 1):

You should write 2 different sql queries.
This line creates the problem

```
else if (($status!=='NULL')){
```

It only runs the update query while the status is not null. But in your case it should run on each case.

```
if($status!='NULL'){
    mysql_query("Update cases Set statistics_status=".$status." Where caseid='".mysql_real_escape_string($case)."'", $connection);
}

if($comments!='NULL'){
    mysql_query("Update cases Set statistics_comments =".mysql_real_escape_string($comments)." Where caseid='".mysql_real_escape_string($case)."'", $connection);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `form` tag has no `action` and no `method`. So, it does not clear, how do you handle form submitting to run a function like `saveTableStatus($case)`. 
But you should know, default `method` for form submitting is `GET`. So when you change `status` and `comment` inputs and submit your form, it posts data as a URL. It may cause problems for handling long URL because of a long comment. So better to use `POST` method for your form like `<form method="POST">`